# Guard won't load WDM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial which is excellent so far. I'm on the Advanced Setup Chapter, where he goes through configuring the Rails environment in a way conducive to TDD. I installed Guard, and it runs properly all the way through running the tests I have in my spec/ folder. But then, it spits out this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter.rb:195:in `require': cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)
```

I have wdm installed. I don't know why it can't load it.

It seems like Listen is having problems loading up WDM. It quits after it says "Guard is now watching..."

I haven't reproduced the rest of the stack trace for obvious reasons. I installed Rails using the latest Rails Installer. What's going on here? Do I need to worry about this? It appears to work at least partially...

Comment: I forgot to add that I actually did do that. That's what's messing me up. I should add that I have two Ruby installations on my system. The one that came with the RailsInstaller, and the one I was using before. I ran 'gem install wdm' from both my regular shell and the RailsInstaller shell, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: I uninstalled both my previous Ruby installation as well as the RailsInstaller installation and re-installed RailsInstaller only. Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So here's what happened. By default, on Windows, Listen is supposed to use polling to check for filesystem changes. For some reason it was trying to use WDM. So, I had to had this to my Gemfile:

```
require 'rbconfig'
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/i
```

Maybe Guard makes Listen try to use WDM?

Comment: It does and it should. https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/149 Unfortunately it's not working atm but guard polling without wdm is pretty much useless if livereload is part of the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Can't find where I got this recommendation from, but I was given the following for running guard across windows and linux:

```
gem 'rb-inotify', github: 'nex3/rb-inotify', platforms: :ruby, require: false
gem 'wdm', platforms: :mingw, require: false
```

The false's make it so the gems are only attempted to be loaded when running on that platform.  Your windows environment may need `mswin` instead of `mingw`, depending on which ruby install you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Like said Binary Phile If you use rails in both windows and unix-like, you should use this in your Gemfile :

```
gem 'wdm','>= 0.1.0', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

it works fine and it's readable.