# how to determinate which conflicts or lack or libraries when uploading rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am very very new on rails, and I have the problem that I am trying to set my project on local machine (the project was already started) and I get tons of error, I firstly did a `bundle install` and after download all gems and libraries I tried with `rails server` , my problem is that I get many errors, and I dont know what I have to install or do in order to make it run.

Any idea? here is my shell result

I think I have to install some libraries.. any idea of these problems?

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter.rb:195:in `
require': cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:195:in `load_dependent_adapter'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:33:in `load_dependent_adapter'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:187:in `usable?'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
s/windows.rb:25:in `usable?'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:179:in `usable_and_works?'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:49:in `block in select_and_initialize'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:47:in `each'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/adapter
.rb:47:in `select_and_initialize'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:267:in `initialize_adapter'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:259:in `setup'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-1.0.2/lib/listen/listene
r.rb:49:in `start'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard.rb:194:in
 `block in start'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard.rb:368:in
 `block in within_preserved_state'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard.rb:365:in
 `synchronize'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard.rb:365:in
 `within_preserved_state'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard.rb:190:in
 `start'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:11
0:in `start'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb
:27:in `run'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:120:in `invoke_command'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in
`dispatch'

        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:43
9:in `start'

from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/guard-1.8.0/bin/guard:6:in `<to
p (required)>'

from C:/Ruby200/bin/guard:23:in `load'
from C:/Ruby200/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just one error, it's just showing you the entire stack.  That is, look at the first line:
    `"C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-.0.2/lib/listen/adapter.rb:195:in 'require': cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)"`

That is the origin of the error.  The lines after that show you what methods were called to get there.

So you only need to solve 
    `"C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/listen-.0.2/lib/listen/adapter.rb:195:in 'require': cannot load such file -- wdm (LoadError)"`

I originally found the answer to this here: [Guard won't load WDM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232960/guard-wont-load-wdm)

The Listen gem needs the WDM Gem to work properly on Windows.  You can accomplish this by adding this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/i
```

This line simply says that if your operating system is 'mwin' or 'mingw', the 'wdm' gem is needed.

Once you've saved your Gemfile, run `bundler install` again to make sure that the wdm gets installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using windows 8 and run into this "-- wdm (LoadError)" ,I was just running ruby (not with rails), a simple "gem install wdm" did the trick.